# Single form, multiple models, using 3rd party application

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am looking to use two forms, and combine them somehow to validate both in one view, so the user only has to use one submit button. I am new to Django, and I am using a third party application, so it is complicating some things. The third party application is providing the `forms.py`, `models.py`, and `views.py` along with a template. What is the best way to do integrate this provided form, with a form of my own and have one submit button?

**forms.py**

```
class ThirdPartyFormOverwrite(ThirdPartyForm):
    tpfield1 = ...
    tpfield2 = ...

class MyCustomForm(forms.Form):
    mcfield1 = ...
    mcfield2 = ...
```

So in the ThirdPartyFormOverwrite class, I am inheriting from the form provided to me by the third party application, and adding some fields. This is working, but I don't know If I should continue to do this (override) the `views.py`. Is there a good way to integrate these two forms without overriding everything the third party app has given me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two forms don't need to reference each other's data to validate, you can just instantiate them both in the view, using the `prefix` argument for at least one of them to keep them distinct.

```
third_party_form = ThirdPartyForm()
my_form = MyCustomForm(prefix="my_form")
```

Then just make sure you add them both to the context and render both in the same `<form>` tag in the template.

If you do need to reference data from one form to validate the other, inheritance sounds like the way to go to me.

Comment: Right - they do not need to reference each other's data to validate. But my question is the third party application is already validating the form in it's own `views.py`. Do I change this view, so I can instantiate my custom form as well? Or do I do this in my own `views.py`?

Comment: You'll have your own view.  If it's appropriate to the situation, you can call (for function-based views) or inherit (for class-based views) the third party one, but it's much more likely that you'll make no direct use of their view than it is that you'll make no direct use of their form.  Bottom line, it depends on what that third party view does and what you're trying to do with yours.